# Req.files in undefined at the server side (built with express & node) when sending files using dropzone

Tags: node.js, express, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone to upload files from the UI. Here is my drozone configuration:

```
 var imageUpload = new Dropzone('div#dataSection', {
        url: 'api/image',
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        paramName: 'file'
      });
```

I am using node and expressjs to build the server side endpoint based on [this link](http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads)

I am excuting below code on the server side.

```
fs.readFile(req.files.displayImage.path, function (err, data) {
  // ...
  var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/uploadedFileName";
  fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
    res.redirect("back");
  });
});
```

**The problem is req.files in coming as undefined. Am I missing anything?**

Comment: You're probably missing a file handling middleware, such as [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: @BenFortune: Thanks for quick reply. But the dropzone docs does not talks about any such middleware. Can you please provide some more information.

Comment: The middleware isn't for Dropzone, it's for Express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [tutorial](http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads) you were following is quite outdated, and certainly written for old version of `express`. With `express` 4.0, released in April 2014, (almost) [all built-in middleware was dropped](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html#core-changes), including the one parsing uploaded files as `req.files`.

That's the problem, and the solution is to use separate module to handle uploaded files. [`Multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) seems like a natural choice for that (kudos to @Ben Fortune for this suggestion).

First, install `multer` Node.js module:

```
npm install multer
```

Then, in the code on server side:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')

var app = express()
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'})) // directory to store uploaded files in
```

After that, all `POST`-ed files should be available as `req.files` in your route handler functions, in the format of [Multer file objects](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#multer-file-object).